# CSS3 Animation Trigger with JQuery Click to Other Element

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css

I have a reddit-like upvote/downvote situation going on in my Rails app and I'm trying to make a CSS3 animation so that when the user clicks any of the downvote links it triggers the animation.

I'm using JQuery like this:

```
<div class="animations">
  <%= image_tag "ballerino.png", class: "fixed no-display", id: "to-animate", style: "margin-top: 80px; width: 40%" %>

  <script>
    $("#downvote").on('click',function() {
      $('#to-animate').removeClass('fixed');
      $('#to-animate').removeClass('no-display');
      $('#to-animate').addClass('animation-left-to-right');
    });
  </script>

</div> <!-- animations -->
```

With this further on down the page as a rendered partial for each `Joke` object:

```
<div class="text-center col-xs-1">
  <% if current_user %>
    <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", joke_up_vote_path(joke), id: "upvote", class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", new_user_session_path, id: "upvote", class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="width: 100%"><h3 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><strong><%= joke.points %></strong></h3></div>
  <% if current_user %>
    <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", joke_down_vote_path(joke), id: "downvote", class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", new_user_session_path, id: "downvote", class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And finally, here's my CSS for my animations from my `application.scss` file:

```
/* ANIMATIONS */

.animation-left-to-right{
  animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*when the spec is finished*/
  -webkit-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
  -moz-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*FF 5+*/
  -o-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Not implemented yet*/
  -ms-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*IE 10+*/
}

@keyframes l-r-ballerina{
  0% { transform:  translate(-400px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ; }
  10% { transform:  translate(-200px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  20% { transform:  translate(-100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  30% { transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  40% { transform:  translate(100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  50% { transform:  translate(300px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  100% { transform:  translate(3000px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
}

@-moz-keyframes l-r-ballerina{
  0% { -moz-transform:  translate(-400px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ; }
  10% { -moz-transform:  translate(-200px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  20% { -moz-transform:  translate(-100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ;  }
  30% { -moz-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  40% { -moz-transform:  translate(100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  50% { -moz-transform:  translate(300px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  100% {-moz-transform:  translate(3000px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% { -webkit-transform:  translate(-400px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ; }
  10% { -webkit-transform:  translate(-200px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  20% { -webkit-transform:  translate(-100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  30% { -webkit-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  40% { -webkit-transform:  translate(100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  50% { -webkit-transform:  translate(300px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  100% { -webkit-transform:  translate(3000px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
}

@-o-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% { -o-transform:  translate(-400px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ; }
  10% { -o-transform:  translate(-200px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  20% { -o-transform:  translate(-100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  30% { -o-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  40% { -o-transform:  translate(100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  50% { -o-transform:  translate(300px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  100% { -o-transform:  translate(3000px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
}

@-ms-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% { -ms-transform:  translate(-400px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ; }
  10% { -ms-transform:  translate(-200px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  20% { -ms-transform:  translate(-100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  30% { -ms-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  40% { -ms-transform:  translate(100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  50% { -ms-transform:  translate(300px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  100% { -ms-transform:  translate(3000px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.no-display {
  display: none;
}
```

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?  I'm new to animations and to JQuery...a bad combination.

**ADDED FIDDLE**

```js
$(".downvote").on('click', function() {
  $('#to-animate').removeClass('fixed');
  $('#to-animate').removeClass('no-display');
  $('#to-animate').addClass('animation-left-to-right');
});
```

```css
/* ANIMATIONS */

.animation-left-to-right {
  animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*when the spec is finished*/
  -webkit-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
  -moz-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*FF 5+*/
  -o-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Not implemented yet*/
  -ms-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*IE 10+*/
}
@keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -o-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -o-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -o-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -ms-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
.no-display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed no-display" id="to-animate" style="margin-top: 80px; width: 40%; background: blue; height: 20px;">
  Box to Animate
</div>

<div class="text-center col-xs-1">


  <div class="width: 100%">
    <a class="upvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" style="margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="width: 100%">
    <h3 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><strong>0</strong></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="width: 100%">
    <a class="downvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this simulates the problem.  I added a div instead of an image, but with the same `id` so it's visible...

Comment: `id` of element within `document` should be unique

Comment: @guest271314 I tried changing it to a class element (both in the partial and in the JQuery), but still no animation shows up.  Do I need it to be an ID?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: @guest271314, as requested, I added a fiddle.  In the fiddle the image is switched to a div just so it's visible, but it's the same concept...

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: @Daan I'm trying to get an animation to trigger whenever anything is downvoted.

Comment: It looks like your snippet is already working than...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not really sure that I understood your problem, but are you expecting something like this ?

```js
$(".downvote").on('click', function() {
  //$('#to-animate').removeClass('fixed');
  $('#to-animate').removeClass('no-display');
  $('#to-animate').addClass('animation-left-to-right');
});
```

```css
/* ANIMATIONS */

.animation-left-to-right {
  animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*when the spec is finished*/
  -webkit-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
  -moz-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*FF 5+*/
  -o-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Not implemented yet*/
  -ms-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*IE 10+*/
}
@keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -o-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -o-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -o-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -ms-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
.no-display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="fixed no-display" id="to-animate" style="margin-top: 80px; width: 40%; background: blue; height: 20px;">
  Box to Animate
</div>

<div class="text-center col-xs-1">


  <div class="width: 100%">
    <a class="upvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" style="margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="width: 100%">
    <h3 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><strong>0</strong></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="width: 100%">
    <a class="downvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That snippet works perfectly, but I'm still trying to understand why.  What did you change?

Comment: Other than commenting out the removal of the 'fixed' class, that is.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments.  I implemented this and the animation begins, but gets cut off when the page refreshes.  This is part of a controller action that has `redirect_to :back` as part of the definition of my `down_vote` method.  How do I sequence this with the animation?

Comment: I awarded you the bounty because I used your answer (mostly), but I'm still working with the javascript to try to get it to work:   `<script>
  $(".downvote").on('click', function() {
    window.location.reload(false); 
    $('#to-animate').addClass('animation-left-to-right');
  });
  </script>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want your page to refresh after the animation end fires or the transition end event fires, you'll need to listen for one or the other.  I've added a listener for both including browser prefixes.  Your animation is long and continues off screen, so it looks pretty quirky, but you get the general idea.

```js
$(".downvote").on('click', function() {
  var href = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934608/css3-animation-trigger-with-jquery-click-to-other-element";
   $('#to-animate').one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function(e) {
    //Stub handler
    //Your logic goes here
    if(confirm("Detected " + e.type + " event.  Redirect to " + href + "?")){
      window.location.href = href;
    } 
   })
  $('#to-animate').removeClass('fixed');
  $('#to-animate').removeClass('no-display');
  $('#to-animate').addClass('animation-left-to-right');
});
```

```css
/* ANIMATIONS */

.animation-left-to-right {
  animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*when the spec is finished*/
  -webkit-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
  -moz-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*FF 5+*/
  -o-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Not implemented yet*/
  -ms-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 4s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*IE 10+*/
}
@keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -o-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -o-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -o-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-400px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-200px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  20% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  40% {
    -ms-transform: translate(100px, 0px) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: translate(3000px, 0px) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
.no-display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed no-display" id="to-animate" style="margin-top: 80px; width: 40%; background: blue; height: 20px;">
  Box to Animate
</div>

<div class="text-center col-xs-1">


  <div class="width: 100%">
    <a class="upvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" style="margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="width: 100%">
    <h3 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><strong>0</strong></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="width: 100%">
    <a class="downvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The purpose of the `fixed` element is so that it doesn't rearrange the elements on the page, but displays on top of whatever is already there.  For this solution, the content shifts down.  Any thoughts?